# Flutter app crashes on launch "Error connecting to the service protocol"

Tags: flutter, dart

I know others have posted about this problem but none of the solutions have worked for me. Been trouble shooting/researching for about 4 hours now and no luck...

Whenever I try to do the "flutter run" command in the terminal on ios(or just running from vs code) The app launches then crashes within the first few seconds giving me the 'Error connecting to the service protocol' error message.

- reseting xcode simulator
- running older version (12.0) of the iphone X sim(along with other phones in the apple ecosystem)
- adding "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1" to the .bash_profile as recommended in other posts similar to this one.

This is the code that I think may cause the error if it is code related not simulator, note that some of the data is not important and is just filler such as the local array data.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
//-----------------Variables--------------------
  final PageController ctrl = PageController();
  List<String> local = ['1', '2', '3']; //fill with events in your area
//----------------------------------------------
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: PageView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      controller: ctrl,
      children: <Widget>[
        StreamBuilder(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('local').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData)
                return const Text('Loading...');
              else {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot userPost = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                    return Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: 350.0,
                      child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                          child: Material(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            elevation: 14.0,
                            shadowColor: Color(0x802196f3),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Container(
                                          width:
                                              MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                          height: 200.0,
                                          child: Image.network(
                                            '${userPost['image']}',
                                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                          )),
                                      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                                      Text('${userPost['title']}',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 20.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
```

expected to have a card displayed showing firestore data but was given this terminal response:

```
Configuring the default Firebase app...
6.1.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000004] App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT does not exist.
6.1.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
6.1.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
6.1.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010904029b __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001085dc735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001090400f5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Runner                              0x0000000102cf5f42 +[FIRApp configure] + 562
    4   Runner                              0x0000000103244c66 -[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin init] + 214
    5   Runner                              0x0000000103244a6c +[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin registerWithRegistrar:] + 300
    6   Runner                              0x0000000102baa360 +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 112
    7   Runner                        <…>
Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: , uri =
http://127.0.0.1:50250/IGi9jQDg97Q=/ws
```

Comment: Do you get this error if you run a brand new flutter project in the same way?

Comment: no its only with this code which leads me to belief its something in the code, or I messed up with connecting firestore?

Answer (score 0):

For Android,
Have you added internet permission in android manifest file?.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

For iOS,

in Info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Just added them and still got the error.. just for clarification I put the code provided at the very bottom of the .plist file, does that sound right?